# $Ra=Rb$ if and only if $aR=bR$

Tags: ring-theory

On which classes of (non commutative) rings we have the following property:
$aR=bR$ if and only if $Ra=Rb$ ?

While I googling around I found the notion of "Duo Ring" in which $aR=Ra$ for every $a\in R$. This is stronger that what I am looking for. Even for this, I don't know any example of duo ring.

Comment: A silly example: division rings work...

Comment: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Florian.Eisele/ArithGrpRng/li.pdf discusses criteria for a group ring to be a duo ring, and gives the example $\mathbb{Q}Q_8$ as a duo ring, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group on 8 elements.

Comment: To expand on the division ring comment, any direct product of division rings is duo, and more generally any strongly von Neumann regular ring is duo. I've also read a few interesting papers by Weimin Xue on exotic duo rings. I sat here for a while trying to see if it was true for right-and-left Ore domains, but no luck. It's true at least that domains with central units have your property.

Answer (score 1):

One place to start would be the third question [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-58/issue-2/Three-questions-on-duo-rings/pjm/1102905665.full), in which the property you are considering is referred to only as (*). Unfortunately, while skimming through articles that cited this paper, I didn't see anything else of particular relevance.

Nonetheless, the paper above proves:

**Theorem.** Let $R$ be a noetherian integrally closed duo domain. Then $aRbR = bRaR$ for all $a,b \in R$ and ideal multiplication is commutative.